# Scraping data using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

In HTMLAgailityPack, how to get the data from the website which is not coming in the innerhtml method of it. For example, if in the link below:

https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=1496#expiry

The table starting with contract symbol is not coming in the innerhtmltext. Please let me know how to get this table data through HTMLAgailityPack?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a GET request to https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?expiryDates=&specId=1496&_=1342907196619

The content is being loaded dynamically via javascript. Perhaps you can parse the innerhtmltext to see what link the javascript will send the GET request to

Comment: can you please elaborate, how to send the get request to the website through the code especialy while parsing an HTMLDocument from it?

Answer (score 0):

If its not 'coming in the innerhtml' that would mean that its being put in there by a script. I'm not able to check this page myself so I'm not sure.

If its coming from a script, you can't get it very easily. You can play around viewing the javascript and maybe being able to read the data as its coming in.

Basically install Firebug on your browser, and look at the data transfers being made. Sometimes you're lucky, sometimes you're not.

Or you can take the simple method and use the winforms WebBrowser control, load it in it, let it run the script then scrape from there. Note that this will leak memory and GDI handles like crazy.

Comment: well i tried with the windows form, the program works fine with window  XP and 32 bits of machine, but on windows 7 with 64 bot machine, it returns the System.__ComObject for all the elements in the web page making me enable to parse the data for the required elements.

Answer (score 0):

Pleae use this XPath to get that table you want  `//*[@id="right"]/div/table`

e.g.

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id="right"]/div/table"));
string html = node.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: but there is no method called selectsinglenode in the HTMLDocument

Comment: doc.documentNode.SelectSingleNode should do it.

Comment: @nishantjain my apologies i typed in a hurry, i have corrected my answer and Haedrian is right

Comment: Hi It gives an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Sorry but i am quite new to this kind of work, so please let me know if i need to take the exact reference of the node given above. If i have to take the reference of actual table tag specified in the page HTML, how do i know that as its not coming on page...

Comment: Below is the code:              
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.OptionReadEncoding = false;
var url =new Uri("https://www.theice.com/productguide/ProductSpec.shtml?specId=1496#expiry");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    document.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
}
}

Comment: HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id="right"]/div/table");
string html = node.InnerHtml;
//System.Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
System.Console.WriteLine(html);  And this is the error:

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
........   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.test() in ConsoleApplicatio
n1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 61
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in

Comment: does you code compiles, please try again by adding your xpath this way "//*[@id=\"right\"]/div/table"

Comment: Yes the code got compile as i added the escape characters to first xpath u sent...

Comment: Hi, Any Advise to look into it?

Comment: @nishantjain I had a look at that apparently the html returned back have malformed html in it that throws error

Comment: Oh, so what do you suggest to get the table content

Comment: Hi @Hatsoft, i tried with "//div[@id=\"right\"]". The error doesnt comes with this, but it didnt show any data. Might be there is not data coming in the code behin or might be the table is loading after it is being parsed. Is there any way to get the data?